# Glue ETL force data type as long

Tags: aws-glue

I have following input:

```
 {
  "customTimeMs": 40
}
```

Glue is reading it as:

```
 |-- customTimeMs: int
```

But I want the type to be long.

If I use a mapping like:

```
Seq(("customTimeMs" , "long" , "customTimeMs" , "long"))
```

It is not casting to long, and I don't want to mention type as an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed mapping to:
Seq(("customTimeMs" ,  "customTimeMs" , "long"))
which works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping should match the input field name and type:

```
val transformedDyf = renamedCrsRecommendations.applyMapping(
  mappings = Seq(
    (("customTimeMs" , "int" , "customTimeMs" , "long"))
  ),
  caseSensitive = false
)
```

Then write dynamic frame `transformedDyf` into a sink.